# System won't boot up because it doesn't have any space

Tags: lubuntu, freeze

My Lubuntu freezes in the login menu whenever I log in

Note:

I've made a partition for the system (10.5GB) which isn't enough...

I tried:

I didn't find any non-system files that I can delete to free up space

I tried to take space from other partitions and add it to this one but it keeps saying "Your system might not boot up"

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but 10.5GB isn't much space..  You'll find you have no space for any additional apps, and not being able to login to a GUI session can be expected when you have no space in $HOME or your user directory is expected.  Text logins will allow login if you've too limited space, but I'd recommend increasing your allocated space on your *unspecified* release of Lubuntu.

Comment: FYI:  I have QA-tested with 10GB as minimum for some releases (*you didn't specify release details which matter as default vary; I didn't use swap when I was using 10GB for example where swapfile is now the default and that file uses space!*) but rarely QA-test with less than 15GB as to me that's too limited a space for a system that will be used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)